# Sandstone Border Bulges

Tags: texturing, node-editor, displacement, masking, bump

I'm some what new to Blender, especially to nodes, so I don't know if this is a beginner question.
[image]

I'm making a Brick Wall texture, from the Rob Tutyel course. The main problem with this wall is the Sandstone border. It's just bulging way too much.

[image]
I hope you can see that hard transition with the Sandstone.

[image]
Here is the hard line, it's really weird and un-realistic.

I've learned why this problem occurs. I'm using a mask maps to tell Blender where and where not do the Brick Wall displacement. For the part where it isn't supposed to do displacement, it just over does it. I don't know if there is some sort of "null" node. But sure as hell sounds useful right now.

[image]
Here is Sandstone mask map. I had to take a snippet of it, because the file size is way to large.

I am aware that the plaster is using the Brick Wall displacement. I was trying to solve one of them, because they are both basically the same thing.

Here is my [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d84c475do3bsvb7/Brick%20Wall.blend?dl=0)

Here is a screenshot of things related to the mask map.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to tell exactly what's happening in your node graph, but I would advise using a *Displacement* node instead of *Bump* to evaluate the height map.  Run it into the *Displacement* input on the *Material Output* node and adjust the *Midlevel* until you can't detect a hard transition.